# How to create new build system on sublime text 4

Tags: windows-10, sublime-text-3, c++, sublime-text

I used sublime text 3. I created a new build system for C++ to take input from the command line. Recently I installed windows 10. So I have to install sublime text again. Now the version of the sublime text is 4. When I am saving the new build system it is not appearing on the build system.

How to create a new build system properly on sublime text 4? Path for new build system on sublime text 4.

Comment: Got the answer.

Location for build system on windows: InstallationFolder\Sublime Text 3\Data\Packages InstallationFolder\Sublime Text\Data\Packages

Comment: Another answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23730866/set-up-python-3-build-system-with-sublime-text-3

save as "C:\Users[username]\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User\SublimeREPL-python.sublime-build"

Answer (score 0):

Just build system and save file as using ( filename.sublime-build) ,now your build system will be apper there.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).